# How do I return limited fields from a search?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have the following query

```
    var searchResult = _Db.Search<PackageRecord>( s => s
        .Index( user.Tenant.Id.ToString () )
        .Type( "Package" )
        .From( request.Page )
        .Size( _DefaultPageSize )

        .Query( q => q.Nested( n => n
            .Path (   f => f.List_BorrowerSet[0] )
            .Query( qm => qm.QueryString( qs => qs
                .OnFields ( 
         f => f.List_BorrowerSet.First().PrimaryBorrower.ContactDetails.Name_Fist, 
         f => f.List_BorrowerSet.First().PrimaryBorrower.ContactDetails.Name_Last
         )
                .Query ( request.BorrowerName ) )
                   && qm
                .Term ( 
                f => f.List_BorrowerSet.First().PrintPosition , 0 )
                ) ) )

        .Fields(
        f => f.Id,
        f=> f.List_BorrowerSet[0].PrimaryBorrower.ContactDetails.Name_Fist,
        f=> f.List_BorrowerSet[0].PrimaryBorrower.ContactDetails.Name_Last
        )

        );
```

How can I get the result with just the limited fields?  I see a document and hits but their object has List_BorrowerSet as null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify `.Fields()` elasticsearch will always return the field selections as key value pairs i.e:

```
"fields" {
    "list_borrowerSet.primaryBorrow.contactDetails.name_Last" : ["Martijn"],
    "list_borrowerSet.primaryBorrow.contactDetails.name_Fist" : ["Laarman"]
}
```

JSON.NET and thus NEST does not quite know how to deserialize these back into a `PackageRecord`

if you would only select `f.List_BorrowerSet` then NEST/JSON.NET can deserialize it properly into `PackageRecord`

You are better off specifying your search as followed:

```
var searchResult = _Db.Search<PackageRecord,CustomPackageRecordSearchHit>( s => s
....
```

Now nest will use `PackageRecord` type to build the search but `CustomPacakgeRecordSearchHit` to deserialize the hits:

```
public class CustomPackageRecordSearchHit
{
    [JsonProperty("list_borrowerSet.primaryBorrow.contactDetails.name_Fist")]
    public IEnumerable<string> BorrowersFirstNames { get; set; }
}
```

Depending on the size of your json this may or may not be a premature optimalization so make sure returning `f.List_BorrowerSet` as a field incurs a signaficant overhead.

Comment: Search<t,y>() does not seem to exist.

Comment: Its not defined on `IElasticClient` so you have to cast to `ElasticClient` huge oversight on my part :(. I'm working hard on getting `IElasticClient` into the shape i want it in the `api-changes` branch for the next release. i.e every call has an *Async variant and less overloads in favor of more descriptors.